# Understanding complex function from fancytext.js

Tags: javascript

Was just going through the code of fancyinput.js and came across the below function(you can also see the same function **[HERE](https://github.com/yairEO/fancyInput/blob/master/fancyInput.js#L339)**):

```
charDir = {
    lastDir : null,
    check : function(s) {      
        var ltrChars    = 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8\u0300-\u0590\u0800-\u1FFF'+'\u2C00-\uFB1C\uFDFE-\uFE6F\uFEFD-\uFFFF',
            rtlChars    = '\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC',
            ltrDirCheck = new RegExp('^[^'+rtlChars+']*['+ltrChars+']'),
            rtlDirCheck = new RegExp('^[^'+ltrChars+']*['+rtlChars+']');

        var dir = rtlDirCheck.test(s) ? 'rtl' : (ltrDirCheck.test(s) ? 'ltr' : '');
        if( dir ) this.lastDir = dir;
            return dir;
    }
}
```

What is this function really doing ? and what is its purpose ?.

if i run the following code in the console:

```
var ltrChars        = 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8\u0300-\u0590\u0800-\u1FFF'+'\u2C00-\uFB1C\uFDFE-\uFE6F\uFEFD-\uFFFF',
    rtlChars        = '\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC',
    rtlDirCheck     = new RegExp('^[^'+ltrChars+']*['+rtlChars+']');

console.log(rtlDirCheck);
```

the value of `rtlDirCheck` turns out to be weird bunch of unreadable characters.

Can anybody explain what this function is doing ?

Comment: @Quentin doesn't matter the code you posted above is all Javascript

Answer (score 1):

This function checks to see which direction the text is going. In languages like English we type left-to-right (`ltr`) but in languages like Arabic they type right-to-left (`rtl`). This function checks for the presence and order of characters commonly found in right-to-left languages and based on if they exist, determine which direction the user writes.